# Initiate class object within function php?

Tags: php, oop

Using class inside a function giving error("Class Not Found");

When using outside function it works. For example -

```
require_once 'DoR/autoload.php';
use DoR\DoR;
use DoR\PSR\DoRx;
$dor = new DoR($agent);
$report = $dor->report();
```

When used within a function it gives error ("CLASS NOT FOUND"), For Example-

```
function runDOR($agent){
    require_once 'DoR/autoload.php';
    $dor = new DoR($agent);
    $report = $dor->report();
    return $report;
}

$report = runDOR();
```

Is their any alternative to having `use` satements for functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the problematic design, you do not necessarily have to have `use` statements.

You can simply do `$dor = new DoR\DoR($agent);` (e.g. use the fully qualified class name).

Also, your first example most certainly does not work. You are importing two classes with the same name (`DoR`) without aliasing either. That won't work.

You've edited that problem out, but even then the `use DoR\PSR\DoRx;` statement is redundant and unnecessary. That class is not used anywhere in that snippet.

Comment: Edited the first Example(typo), $dor = new DoR\DoR($agent); works but what about the use DoR\PSR\DoRx;, how to load this class.

Comment: You are not using that class inside the function. You are using only `DoR\DoR`. And to use either without writing a `use` statement, just use the fully qualified name. Same with each case.